# Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found laravel

Tags: laravel

i bought a laravel script
it's working fine but any route i try to add i get error
here is simple route

```
Route::get('/greeting', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

not working but dashboard is working anything in the script work fine but adding any route i get that error

```
<?php

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Web Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register web routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider within a group which
| contains the "web" middleware group. Now create something great!
|
*/

Auth::routes();

Route::group(['middleware' => 'auth'], function() {
    Route::get('/dashboard', 'HomeController@dashboard');
});
Route::get('/greeting', function () {
    return 'Hello World';
});
```

Comment: Maybe the routes are cached? Try running the command `php artisan route:clear`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IGP solution work fine it was a cache problem
thank you

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comment by IGP, you should try to clear the route cache first.

If that does not help, you should take a look at the `RouteServiceProvider` to make sure that your route file gets called from there.

You can also try to adjust the order (if more than one routing file is called) so that your route file is evaluated before the others (the first matching route "wins").

Also please check the route config of the bought script as it could contain a catch-all/wildcard route.